# InfoBubble not calculating div height properly in Safari

Tags: javascript, google-maps, safari

I'm trying to use a customized Info Window implementation with Google Maps API v3 called [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/). As I was doing my development locally, Safari rendered the bubbles fine. However, when I uploaded it to a live server, it no longer calculated the heigh of the bubble content correctly and displays a scrollbar (which I don't want) (see http://luketilley.com/maps/).

I have done some investigating and it looks like the problem comes from this bit of code:

```
InfoBubble.prototype.getElementSize_ = function(element, opt_maxWidth,
                                            opt_maxHeight) {
var sizer = document.createElement('DIV');
sizer.style['display'] = 'inline';
sizer.style['position'] = 'absolute';
sizer.style['visibility'] = 'hidden';


if (typeof element == 'string') {
  sizer.innerHTML = element;
} else {
  sizer.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true));
}

document.body.appendChild(sizer);
var size = new google.maps.Size(sizer.offsetWidth, sizer.offsetHeight);

// If the width is bigger than the max width then set the width and size again
if (opt_maxWidth && size.width > opt_maxWidth) {
  sizer.style['width'] = this.px(opt_maxWidth);
  size = new google.maps.Size(sizer.offsetWidth, sizer.offsetHeight);
}

// If the height is bigger than the max height then set the height and size
// again
if (opt_maxHeight && size.height > opt_maxHeight) {
  sizer.style['height'] = this.px(opt_maxHeight);
  size = new google.maps.Size(sizer.offsetWidth, sizer.offsetHeight);
}

document.body.removeChild(sizer);
delete sizer;
return size;
};
```

Specifically, this line:

```
var size = new google.maps.Size(sizer.offsetWidth, sizer.offsetHeight);
```

Upon investigating what values safari reports, I confirmed that safari does indeed report different values when displaying the page locally vs. online.

Doing more testing, I also found that the issues only start when I add an image to the info bubble (check the marker off the coast of Africa).

here is the content that I'm trying to put in the info_bubble

```
info_content = '<div class="bubble">' +
                            '<h1>' + markerData.name + '</h1>' +
                            '<div class="icons">' +
                            icon_html +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<img src="' + markerData.image + '"/>' +
                            '<p>' + markerData.description + '</p>' +
                            '<p><a target="_blank" href="' + markerData.url + '"><img src="learn_more.png"/></a></p>' +
                        '</div>';
```

Any ideas on what's happening here? is there a better way to calculate the required size?

**Update:** This may be a bug with Safari. I just spent some time in the debugger and if I set a breakpoint and manually step through the functions, it does the right thing, but if I just let it run, it continues to misbehave. So I guess the question is now: is there a workaround?

Comment: Hmm, I have a problem with Maps v3 + InfoBubble + Safari 7.0, too. But it's not that something gets a wrong size, it's that I don't get the infobubble at all. Also in your linked map I don't get any bubble, the map aligns for the bubble to come out, but that's it. Also for me it makes no difference if it's a local or a remote page